# Вставить iframe с большим количеством видео с различных ресурсов

Tags: php, dle, iframe

С движком DLE работаю впервые, на сайте нужно вставить новости с большим количеством видео с различных ресурсов, нужно на время разрешить использование тега `<iframe>`.

Опасность связанная с этим не критична. Из файла `parse.classes.php` удалял `iframe` из блэк листа, но не помогло. Если кто-то знает решение, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

попробуй сделать стат. страницу без ифрейма, а потом отредактировать в phpmyadmin, так вроде бы можно обойти это ограничение.  Если не помогает редактирование файла